# jquery modify values to combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox

I have two combobox in my web. I need modify the values of second combobox dynamically.
The first combo define the number of elements in the second combo, but it don't work.
the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var numPest = $("select[name='numOpc']").val();
var active;
$("select").change(function(){
    numPest = $("select[name='numOpc']").val();
    alert(target+" "+numPest);
    for(var i = 1 ; i < parseInt(numPest) + 1 ; i++ ){
        $("#tabAct").append($("<option></option>").val(i).html(i));
    } 
});
$("#tabAct").change(function(){
    active = $("select[name='tabAct']").val();
    alert(active);
});
```

The html code:

```
    <select name="numOpc" id="numOpc" >
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="divTab">
    <select name="tabAct">
    </select><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access 'tabAct' by ID in your jQuery code, but in HTML only name is specified.